# How can I connect the ground planes to GND?

Tags: pcb-design, ground, proteus, ground-plane

I'm trying to make a double-sided PCB in Proteus Ares. I added the planes using the Power Plane Generator tool, but there is no connection between planes and ground, if that makes sense. The only option in the Net menu is "none" so I can't really select anything. How can I connect the planes with actual ground? I included the PCB design and ground plane parameters:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Proteus Ares, but it looks to me as though you do not have *any* net names defined in your design. Is this PCB based on a schematic in the same project from which you've imported a netlist into the PCB design, or are you just drawing the PCB "freehand" with no linked schematic or netlist?

Comment: @brhans  I'm drawing freehand because I was having some problems with the pre-defined pins. For example SMD package in Proteus is incorrect, compared to the datasheet.

Comment: Well then if you have not imported a netlist from a schematic then you won't have a ground (or any other) net in your PCB design. It's possible that you can create a net "manually" in the PCB editor.

Comment: If the default footprint for a component is incorrect, find or create the correct footprint.  If you do any amount of schematic design and PCB layout, you WILL have to create your own schematic symbols and PCB footprints.  Any reasonable CAD system will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Select the net you want you plane connected to from the "Net:" drop down menu.

[image]

Assuming you have named your ground "GND", select GND from the drop down menu.

Comment: Thank you for the information but the problem is that only option in the Net drop down menu is none so I can't do what you just said.